# Monodevelop will not start in Mint 17

Tags: monodevelop, linux-mint

I am trying to install MonoDevelop in Linux Mint 17.  I have installed both using `apt` and throught he package manager, but I'm getting the same result.  MonoDevelop simply will not start.  I try to run it from the command line and I get no output and no splash screen.  Just nothing happens.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Turns out I was missing dependencies.  I installed `mono-complete` and `gtk-sharp3` and it works now

Comment: I also needed to install "gnome-sharp2" to get rid of an error after this. (running Ubuntu(Don't know if that is the actual reason))

Comment: Thanks for this.  I sometimes wonder if I'm the only one who thinks that, one, dependency resolution is the kind of thing a package manager should really be handling automatically, and two, that some sort of error should probably be displayed when a program can't start due to missing dependencies.

Comment: @Doug Warren I guess the problem is that developers mostly want to concentrate on the code and don´t really want to think about dependencies so this is what we get, even in 2020

Answer (score 9):

For those not covered by the accepted answer (e.g. because there is no `mono-complete` anymore), here is the latest fix:

```
sudo apt-get install libmono-cairo2.0-cil
```

Source:

http://binbashblog.blogspot.gr/2013/11/monodevelop-crashes-on-startup-in-linux.html
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=168931

Comment: Using repositories from http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/ there is a mono-complete package. Accepted solution still applies and had solved my case. A previous install of cairo was not sufficient for solving the startup crash issue with current monodevelop.

Comment: Default repositories in Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64-bit allowed for the installation of the mono-complete package.

Comment: Newest Ubuntu with Gnome 3 and I can confirm that neither mono-complete nor gtk-sharp3 was sufficient enough. Installing libmono-cairo4.0-cil fixed the issue and monodevelop is  now starting